# Git - number of lines changed when bad history

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

I have to calculate numbers of code added/removed per commit, in a git repo, but I have said repo a bit borked. At one point, one of the devs duplicated same commit, ammended one of them, pulled without rebase and merged them afterwards.

The history is (part of it):

`D
 | \
 C  |
 |  B
 | /
 A`

Both B and C removed the same files (resulting in 48k lines removed per commit) and then created an empty D commit. C added some files that B didn't.

I'm running `git log --shortstat --reverse --pretty=oneline > log.txt` command to get the log and then read it line by line and add/substract values returned.

The bit from the log (simplified for brevity):

`SHA-A message
4 files changed, 134 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
SHA-B message
6 files changed, 48337 deletions(-)
SHA-C message
13 files changed, 9 insertions(+), 48342 deletions(-)
SHA-D Merge branch 'feature/B' of origin into feature/B`

I also tried using [git-loc](https://github.com/ITikhonov/git-loc)

the output is:

`2018-01-09 15:31:00       10   +10    -0 c3694d2 DemoBytom@gmail.com    A
2018-01-09 15:33:22        0    +0   -10 dc17b64 DemoBytom@gmail.com    B
2018-01-09 15:33:48       -8    +2   -10 9cad481 DemoBytom@gmail.com    C
2018-01-09 15:34:50       -8    +0    -0 f22017c DemoBytom@gmail.com    Merge branch 'origin/feature/B' into feature/B
2018-01-09 15:34:56       -8    +0    -0 9e495a1 DemoBytom@gmail.com    Merge branch 'feature/B'`

Now - the question is - can I somehow get a proper number of code, in the commit, even if some deletions/insertions are duplicated and then merged?

I need to present statistics of how our repositories changed, and how much code was written in different periods of time, I cannot show them with negative values, nor can I, realistically, go through each commit in each repo to find such occurencies. Are there any tools that could present proper number of lines, at each commit step?

[Example repository](https://github.com/DemoBytom/borkedGit)

Comment: Try if adding the `--first-parent` parameter to `git log` shows something better, you should probably only count changes "on" the branch you're on, merges would introduce those changes on the branch as changes, *if those files changed in the merge*, and you probably don't want to count both merge commits and the commits it merges in. So see if that parameter, which should "follow the branch" creates better numbers.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work if the part shown above was merged into master branch (example repo). Then log shows only A 10 insertions and merge commit  without any changes (??), especially doesn't show the insertions into new file in C commit. The end result would be 10 lines, while in reality it should be 10 removed and 2 added by the merge commit.